# Как подключить js библиотеку в typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Нужена js библиотека 'react-keydown' в typescript проекте. Тайпингов для этой библиотеки  нету.

```
    /// <amd-dependency path="./node_modules/react-keydown" />
     declare var require:(moduleId:string) => any;
```

и потом require('react-keydown');

то при использовании браузер выдает еррор
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ^

```
   module.exports = ^1.5.0;
   /*****************
    ** WEBPACK FOOTER
    ** external "^1.5.0"
    ** module id = 7
    ** module chunks = 0
    **/
```

в конфиге webpack напсано :

```
    externals: {
    "react": "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
    "react-keydown": "^1.5.0"
},
```

Как решить мою проблему ?